# Vue list is rendering two times and lags

Tags: forms, vue.js, v-for

I have a strange bug when creating a list.

array "mostFrequentlyUsed" is data from a database

mostFrequentlyUsed:

```
[{hash: "fc2as9", isSelected: false, name: "Banan",  ratio: 100, type: "FOOD_ITEM"},
{hash: "sd21sf", isSelected: false, name: "Scrambled eggs",  ratio: 24, type: "RECIPE"}]
```

Code that is responsible for rendering list

```
<v-flex v-if="mostFrequentlyUsed.length" xs12>
            <v-list two-line>
              <template v-for="(meal, index) in mostFrequentlyUsed">
                <v-list-tile :key="meal.hash">
                  <v-list-tile-content>
                    <v-list-tile-title>{{ meal.name }}</v-list-tile-title>
                    <v-text-field
                      v-if="meal.isSelected && meal.type === 'RECIPE'"
                      v-model.number="meal.ratio"
                      color="secondary"
                      type="number"
                      prepend-inner-icon="mdi-minus-box"
                      append-icon="mdi-plus-box"
                      @click:append="meal.ratio += 0.1"
                      @click:prepend-inner="meal.ratio -= 0.1"
                    />
                  </v-list-tile-content>
                  <v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-checkbox
                      v-model="meal.isSelected"
                    />
                  </v-list-tile-action>
                </v-list-tile>
                <v-divider v-if="index + 1 < mostFrequentlyUsed.length" :key="index" />
              </template>
            </v-list>
          </v-flex>
```

I suspect that the list is rendering two times and this is the reason why all view is lagging.
[image]

Additionally, I noticed, if I comment line responsible for rendering name, the view is not lagging.

This is how I fetch `mostFrequentlyUsed`:

```
apollo: {
    myMostFrequentlyChosen: {
      query: QUERY_MOST_FREQUENTLY_USED,
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
      result(data) {
        const mostFrequentlyUsed = path(['data', 'myMostFrequentlyChosen'], data)
        this.mostFrequentlyUsed = mostFrequentlyUsed
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure there is no duplicated `meal.hash`? Have you tried `:key="index"`?

Comment: I am sure, I tried with ```:key="index"```, no difference :(

Comment: How do you return the `mostFrequentlyUsed`? Could you post the code?

Comment: @geauser I added how to I'm fetching  ```mostFrequentlyUsed```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Apollo but from what I can understand you are doing something rather weird, why not use a `computed` named `mostFrequentlyUsed` based on the fetch ed value `myMostFrequentlyChosen`? I would advise you install vuejsdevtools plugin on your browser and look at the value of `mostFrequentlyUsed` it could be really helpful

Comment: I re-read your edit and it seems that the value of `mostFrequentlyUsed` is in reality the same as `mostFrequentlyChosen` is it a wanted feature?

Comment: It's changes nothing. Idk, whats is wrong with this view, I worked 10 hours to fix it and I still can't fix it. Probably I need a rest. Thank for your help. If I fix it, I'll post an answer.